# </div> shows up red with < operator not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, comparator, fatal-error

For some reason my .php file is showing the `</div>` tag in red.

```
  <div class="self-center tab__number p-12 xl:text-18 font-semibold
  ">
    @if( $tab_counter < 10 ){{0}}@endif{{$tab_counter}}
  </div>
```

When I change `$tab_counter < 10` to `$tab_counter &lt; 10` it changes to green like the opening `<div>`, but I'm confused. Since it's a .php file, shouldn't it still work with `<`?

Note that this file is also showing the error message:

> Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the
> PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change
> by some other means, such as by using SFTP.

so it might be unrelated. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The color coding in your editor is produced by the editor, which apparently doesn't recognize that the **@** is supposed to indicate code (I assume it does? I'm not actually familiar with WP theming). If the code actually works, sometimes it's best to just ignore the editor's shortcomings (or get a better one).

Comment: I am using the built in Theme Editor actually. The @ does indicate code, however I didn't personally write any of it, it was all provided by the company originally hired to build this website.

Comment: Interesting. Does it work when you replace the **<** with **&lt;** (have you been able to upload your change)? I guess strictly speaking the code fragment is a text node of the **div** element node and ought to be html-encoded.

Comment: I have not been able to upload the change. I can edit the file but it won't let me save it.